# How can i make errorpages in jsf?

Tags: jsf, netbeans, error-handling

Everytime something gets wrong .. i got to see this.

[image]

How can i make a simple Errorpage with stacktrace in jsf ?

Answer (score 4):

If you use [Facelets](https://facelets.dev.java.net/) (which is almost mandatory if you want to develop JSF webapps), an error page is automatically created. You can see an example [here](https://facelets.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/error.html).

More generally, you can [customize your web.xml](http://e-docs.bea.com/wls/docs70/webapp/web_xml.html#1045452) in order to redirect the user when an error occurs.